# How to add files in AWS CodePipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I'm pretty new with AWS and I deployed an Python + Flask app to Elastic Beanstalk using CodePipeline with GitHub but I need to add some certs files that are not included in GitHub as they are in .gitignore and I haven't found a tutorial to do that.
Can anyone know if it's possible to add that files to CodePipeline?
I appreciate your help, regards!

Answer (score 0):

There are **two choices** that you can use:

1. Add [CodeBuild](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodeBuild.html) action to your CP which will add the certs to your deployment artifacts.
2. Use [.ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) to add code to your deployment package which will add the needed certificates when your CP deploys to Elastic Beanstalk.